# Ruby Array Search Method Not Working As Intended

Tags: arrays, ruby, search, methods

I am having trouble making the search method that i wrote in my script to work. Here is the relevant code from the script:

```
$records = []

def xml_extractor(document)
    document.xpath("//record").each do |record|
        $records << {"id" => record.xpath('id').text, 
            "first_name" => record.xpath('first_name').text, 
            "last_name" => record.xpath('last_name').text, 
            "email" => record.xpath('email').text, 
            "gender" => record.xpath('gender').text, 
            "ip_address" => record.xpath('ip_address').text,
            "send_date" => record.xpath('send_date').text,
            "email_body" => record.xpath('email_body').text,
            "email_title" => record.xpath('email_title').text}
            puts record
        end
    puts "\nAll records loaded!"
end


def search_by_ip(ip)
    record_to_return = $records.select {|k| k["ip_address"] == ip.to_s}
    puts JSON.pretty_generate(record_to_return) 
end
```

Basically my xml_extractor method works fine and it stores everything into the array using nokogiri. The xml file that is being implemented has a thousand records each having its own first_name, last_name etc. But the problem is when i try to implement the search_by_ip method on the array a "null" value is returned, when what the method should really be doing is returning the entire record that belongs to that specific ip address. Also, i realised that every time i implement the xml_extractor method, i.e. when an xml document is parsed in into the array, the contents arent really saved in rather they are only displayed for while the loop is going. Which might be why I get a "null" for my search methods. Let me know what you guys think though.

Comment: let your xml_extractor return the records, no need for a public variable, check the content of what is returned, give this array as a second parameter to search_by_ip. Better still make a collection class records with its methods like search_by_ip

Comment: Sorry but could you please elaborate upon your points in code because im fairly new to ruby, i understand your points i just dont really know how to implement them. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an example of how to use OO to obtain what you want.
I don't have your document so I simplified your document to a 2 dimensional array
In the method read switch the comment to work with your xml
Each method can be chained and does only what is required
They can all be tested separatly (here by p'ting them)

```
class Xml_extractor

  attr_reader :document, :records

  def initialize document
    @document = document
    @records  = []
  end

  def read
    # @document.xpath("//record").each do |record|
    @document.each do |record|
      @records << {id: record[0], ip_address: record[1]}
    end
    self # return self so that you can chain another method
  end

  def search_by_ip(ip)
    #return first of an array if found, nil otherwise
    # attention to use a hash key here to search, not a string
    @records.select {|k| k[:ip_address] == ip.to_s}.first
  end

end

document = [[0, "192.168.0.1"], [1, "192.168.0.2"]]
p Xml_extractor.new(document).read.records
# [{:id=>0, :ip_address=>"192.168.0.1"}, {:id=>1, :ip_address=>"192.168.0.2"}]
p Xml_extractor.new(document).read.search_by_ip("192.168.0.2")
# [{:id=>1, :ip_address=>"192.168.0.2"}]
p Xml_extractor.new(document).read.search_by_ip("192.168.0.2").to_json
# "[{\"id\":1,\"ip_address\":\"192.168.0.2\"}]"
```

Comment: now i get what you mean thank you so much for clarifying it for me and helping me out with this the code works perfectly now.

Comment: you are welcome, could you please accept the answer an upvote ?

Comment: sorry i am new to the site so i didnt know how to do it but i gave you one, thanks again.

Comment: I see no change, you need to click the checkmark left to my answer otherwise the aswer keeps being unaswered. Upvoting is by clicking the up arrow above the 0

Answer (score 0):

In ruby your method will return the last line. If you want your method to return data, you need to return it on the last line.  `puts` doesn't return anything.
Try to change like this:

```
def search_by_ip(ip)
  record_to_return = $records.select {|k| k["ip_address"] == ip.to_s}
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(record_to_return)
  record_to_return
end
```